# EventTrigger dependent on EventProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers

I've been "struggleing" with this issue for some time.

I want to make a simple selection tool. I've bunch of Borders that contains a MouseDown() event.

```
        <Border Name="Column1_0800" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
        <Border.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Name="Column1_ColorBrush" Color="LightBlue"/>
        </Border.Background>
        <Border.Triggers>       
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseDown">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation 
                            Duration="0:0:0.5"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="Column1_ColorBrush"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                            To="Gray"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Border.Triggers>
    </Border>
```

My issue is that I want the Mouse.MouseDown be depedent on Mouse.MouseEnter.

Pseudo:
If Mouse.MouseEnter = triggered then Mouse.MouseEnter = Fire.

I've searched around the web for solutions and what I've found so far:

[ButtonBase.IsPressed Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.ispressed.aspx%22%22)

[Triggers WPF](http://wpftutorial.net/Triggers.html%20%22%22)

*This is my first question on Stack so if you see something I do that you don't like, let me know on a comment below.*

Thanks In Advance,
Secondmail Notch.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a field/property to your window which gets turned on/off by the mouse entering/leaving the control. On the mouse down/click you can check if that flag is on or off - if it's on then call your method.

Comment: Can you make an example?